# C# Winform using Interop with microsoft outlook 365 application client

Tags: c#, winforms

im kinda stuck here, im trying to build an application that open up outlook client with the message, title, address etc

but when im trying to actually send the message im getting the following error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral.

i know that interop is for office 2013, is there any other alternatives to use instead of it? or to force interop to use MSOffice 365?

Comment: Download the PIAs from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Answer (score 0):

I’ve managed to eventually use “mailto:” by starting an new process as with an url which there I have “mailto:xx@mail.com?subject=xxx” and use outlook as default mail program in windows 10, then it worked to me without interop